# Query: Emirates ID (UAE )Front and Back Matching

Tags: microblink, blinkid

I had implemented the Microblink Framework Version: 4.6.0 for iOS without installing Cocoapods and doing the **Integration without CocoaPods**.

I am using my own customized overlay view controller by passing it to your **MBViewControllerFactory**.

I am scanning the Emirates ID front and back with that and it is working fine, Just want to confirm the matching logic for the same that I had written for it. Please refer the below code for Matching Logic I had done.

```
MBUnitedArabEmiratesIdFrontRecognizer *emiratesIDFrontData = (MBUnitedArabEmiratesIdFrontRecognizer *)recognizer;

NSString *emiratesIdNumberFront = [emiratesIDFrontData.result.idNumber stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"-" withString:@""];

MBUnitedArabEmiratesIdBackRecognizer *emiratesIDBackData = (MBUnitedArabEmiratesIdBackRecognizer *)recognizer;

if([emiratesIdNumberFront isEqualToString: emiratesIDBackData.result.mrzResult.opt1]) {

       NSLog(@"It's A Match");
} else {

       NSLog(@"Please Try Again");

}
```

Is the above code fine for matching the Emirates ID Front and Back or Do I have to match some other keys as well for getting the proper match?

Answer (score 2):

Your matching logic is correct for the document number from the front and backside of the EIDA.

The idNumber is the only class that is present on both the front and the back of the document in a similar form (from the front side result is returned with the dashes (-) but you already replace them in your matching logic). So your matching logic should work properly. 
Great job on this!

I also want to mention that v4.6.0 is a quite older version of the SDK (released on Jan 25, 2019). In our latest version of BlinkID 5.4.0 (released on Apr 28, 2020) you can use BlinkIdCombinedRecognizer which automatically scans front and the backside of the document in a single camera opening for all documents (not just EIDA) and your matching logic would also work there without any problems.